# AWS S3 restrict access based on object age

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-policies, aws-iam-policy

[I know I can allow date based access to S3 files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws-dates.html), however is it possible to allow access to certain files in S3 by the age of the object itself?

E.g. something like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "service-prefix:action-name",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "DateGreaterThan": {"aws:last_modified": "2020-04-01T00:00:00Z"},
                "DateLessThan": {"aws:last_modified": "2020-06-30T23:59:59Z"}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything related to object age or last modified timestamp at [Condition keys for Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/list_amazons3.html#amazons3-policy-keys). Wonder if you could tag these objects with their last modified timestamp (and perhaps automate that for new objects via Lambda), then write a policy dependent on [aws:ResourceTag/tag-key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-resourcetag)?

Comment: oh tags would work great actually! @jarmod

Comment: Do the tags persist if I overwrite the object? Or do I need to add the tag back every time? @jarmod

Comment: I would not expect the tags to persist. You're essentially uploading a new object, albeit with the same key. Probably easy to test this. But, an S3 event-triggered Lambda function could be the solution to that.

Comment: An alternative to using tags is to transition your object to a particular storage class (after it is old enough for you) via a lifecycle rule, then use s3:x-amz-storage-class in the bucket policy to deny access.

EDIT: not sure if it would work with GETs, as the documentation only mentions that for PUTs. I think you should try and see what works best.

Comment: tag is your best option

Comment: Can I ask... _Why_ do you want to restrict access based on `LastModified` date?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein an easy way to allow sample historical data and paid/live data.

Comment: I would recommend you do this by either placing 'historical' and 'live' data in different paths (eg `life/`, `historical/`) or setting permissions based on the Key (filename). For example, if an object is named with a date (`2020-06-30_file3.csv`), then allow access based on a Prefix (`2020-06`). It would have less resolution (eg by whole months), but it would mean that files do not need to be moved as they age.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein tags work nicely. Different paths == more storage costs. Setting by prefix when you want to provide 20+ years or differing years will get messy.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no such condition key to gate access on the age of an object. See [the complete list of S3-specific condition keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/list_amazons3.html#amazons3-policy-keys).